# Spliting a vector and organizing in a list in R

Tags: r

This is my vector:

```
words<-c("a~b","c~d","e~f","g~h","i~j","k~l","m~n","o~p","q~r","s~t","u~v")
```

This is the output that I need: `final<-as.list(letters[1:22])`

This is what I did:

```
    words<-c("a~b","c~d","e~f","g~h","i~j","k~l","m~n","o~p","q~r","s~t","u~v")

    aa<-strsplit(words, "~")

wronglist<-lapply(aa,function(x) strsplit(x, "~"))
```

The vector `wronglist`has too much brackets and levels. I need a "cleaner" list.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 4):

An option is to `unlist` the `list` output after the `strsplit`

```
out <- as.list(unlist(strsplit(words, "~")))
identical(out, final)
#[1] TRUE
```

or use `scan`

```
as.list(scan(text = words, sep="~", what = "", quiet = TRUE))
```